# Chance of revival of The Mishna Project?

Tags: product-recommendation, music

The (now defunct) [Mishna Project](http://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-3520405,00.html) was a startup band that set Mishnayoth to music in an attempt to make learning Mishnah more accessible.

I have their first album (which I highly recommend, if you can find it), and I'm interested in knowing whether there are any plans to revive the project and have more products produced. Does anyone know? Of course, the project's founders know, so if anyone knows a way for me to contact them, that'd be a good answer.

Comment: why close?.....

Comment: -1. This is a question on how to reach certain persons. Yes, those persons are Jewish, and, yes, they were involved in Jewish life and learning, but, well, this question is seeking telephone-directory assistance and is not about JL&L. I'm very tempted to close this as out of scope, but will discuss it (now) on chat first and see what others think; or comment here.

Comment: @msh210 I neither agree nor disagree. I see both sides of the issue. I just thought it was worth a shot. If the community wants to close it, I'll just delete it.

Comment: @msh210 You wrote -1 but I don't see any downvotes on the question...

Comment: For future reference, that chat starts at http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3825836#3825836. @DoubleAA: fixed now. `:-)`

Comment: @msh210 I wan't implying you had to. Just curious...

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd like to see this reopened, because I've seen a hint of life with the project. A friend shared a YouTube video of a class taught by now-Rabbi Dovid Weinberg singing a "new" song of theirs (video was posted a year ago).

Answer (score 7):

They can be reached at themishnaproject@gmail.com - Good luck.

Comment: I sent them an e-mail and will post the response when I get an answer.

Comment: I am still awaiting a response.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling their band email might be defunct as well. Let us know if you find anything out.

Comment: anything?.......

Comment: Never got a response.

Comment: Try re-sending that email?